# HD60X Game capture getting wrong aspect ratio from Canon EOS M50

Tags: canon, obs

I am outputting a HDMI signal from my camera Canon EOS M50, capturing it with HD60X game capture.

In OBS, it appears cropped and with wrong aspect ratio, Why?

[image]

Pressing info to get rid of info icons, still no cake:

[image]

The camera is set to filming mode

[image]

with resolution 1920x1080

[image]

This is also how I setup OBS

[image]

Comment: Are you actually hitting Record in the camera? idk how Cannon works for this, but my Nikon doesn't drop its normal 4:3 image to 16:9 until the moment I hit the internal Record button.

Comment: No, I do not hit record. Do I need to do that? Then I still will have the 30 minute cap.

Comment: Maybe they made the output useless on purpose?